# How do I include statistical significant index in bar chart in excel?

Tags: statistics

[image]

I want to have a star dot above each bar chart. I don't know how to present that index. Please anyone help me to resolve this problem,

Comment: Create a dummy data set and set its point as a star dot. Stack overflow may be better for excel questions as it is not statistics really.

Comment: What kind of dummy data should be added? And how to set a star dot? I am really still fuzzy in this matter, if you dont mind to give me more explanation..

Comment: Use the add data function, x values you already have, y values can be zero or 1 or whatever value to get the stardot where you need it - but make the data line blank so it is not seen.

Comment: Another trick is to make a second chart which is transparent except for the data and lay it on top of the first - did that once - what looked like a single chart was actually six - the people trying to steal the work were tearing thier hair out as they couldn’t get their chart to work :) :)

Comment: Thank you very much Solar mike!! I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite seriously:   *Friend Don't Let Friends Use Excel*.   Learn to use Matlab/Octave, or python,  or R,  or just plain Gnuplot.
No matter what tool you use, since "significance" is a separate variable, you need to convert your collection of "*" , "**"  etc to numeric values and plot the desired symbols at the matching category locations.

Comment: Thank you Carl Witthoft.. It is solved already.. thank you alot, I really appreciate it

Comment: Or the up-and-coming [Julia](https://julialang.org) language with some world-class scientific applications [here](https://juliacomputing.com).